# Xamarin Offline Location How we get Offline location through GPS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, geolocation

How we get Offline location through GPS?

I try but `Xam.Plugin.GeoLocator` fails in offline mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml:

```
 <Button Text="location"
            TextColor="Black"
            Clicked="Button"/>

    <Label Text="longi"
           TextColor="Gray"
           FontSize="Small"/>
    <Label x:Name="longit"
           FontSize="10"
           TextColor="Orange"/>


    <Label Text="Latitu"
           TextColor="Gray"
           FontSize="Small"/>

    <Label x:Name="latit"
           FontSize="10"
           TextColor="Orange"/>
```

Code:

```
 private async void Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
                var post = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                longit.Text = post.Longitude.ToString();
                latit.Text = post.Latitude.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

Permissions:

```
 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
     string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on iPhone the `Flight Mode` disables most of the GPS functions. So for `Offline Mode` as in `Flight Mode` that is actually the correct behavior. However, if you turn off `WiFi` `Cellular` and `Bluetooth` individually or just have no network available, `GPS` should be available.

If this does not answer your question, you may want to disclose a bit more info on your usecase, a specific error or even the code sample that seems to fail where it should not.